# Copy files using java. FileUtils.copyFiles vs os cmd copy?

Tags: java

I'm curious if it's better to use Process executor to copy files or if it's better to use Java copy methods.

Comment: Why go through the process of creating new processes for something which you can do inline?

Comment: OS command will probably be OS specific .

Comment: Define 'better'. If you want performance, almost certainly the OS command will be quicker. If you want portability, the OS command doesn't qualify. Not a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your program as portable as possible with respect to functionality.

If you use `cmd copy`, you have to test the platform and handle it for every platform. If you use `cmd copy` you may not even cover all the platforms. You have to deal with all subtleties behind the different `copy` processes of different `platforms`. You need to know how every such process should be used, how parameters should be passed and all.

So, I would say you go for using your `FileUtils`. Because, your functionality will be more portable.

Comment: prior to java 1.5 there is no file copy method....

Comment: @AlexWien well, yeah.. edited...

Comment: check if file copy was may introduced even later, java 7?

Comment: @AlexWien please tell me your point directly....

Comment: The point is that java has introduced File copy very late, I dont have time to find that out which was the first version. FileUtils is an external lib (Appache.commons), and the way to go prior to Java 1.7

Answer (score 1):

better you use java copy methods as if you changed the platform than also your code able to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a java program and you want to copy files from within that java program, you should definitely use the FileUtils.

1. You have more control over the copying process, like checking path validity and other stuff. If you call an external command to do this, you have additional overhead of error checking, wehich gets much more complicated this way.
2. Additionally, if your program is used on some other platform it may suddenly not work, because you don't know how to call a native copy command there. You would have to provide a separate solution for each differently supported platform, which somehow defeates the purpose of using Java.
3. Calling an external process is much more expensive and slower. After all, the OS has to create a new process and perform all the tasks associated with it, PLUS you have to check all possible error conditions. Command is not where you think it is, Command doesn't execute, a different version behaves slightly differently. How to check if it worked? and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for using the Java copy methods for the portability reasons that others have stated, but I think it'll also simplify error handling in your code.

The only reason I would consider using the OS commands would be if the ***major*** functionality of your application was to copy files around and there was a considerable performance difference between the OS and Java implementations.

If copying files is just a minor part of the app, go for Java.